# How to define a function in latex language that takes as an argument the name of an image?

Tags: macros

I am new to latex.
I am able to define symbols for instance:

```
\newcommand{\imageA}{\includegraphics[width=3em,valign=c]{image_01}}
```

I can call this symbol (`\imageA`) multiple times thus greatly simplifying my code.

How can I define a function that is similar to the symbol above except that it can take the name of an image as an argument `\functionA{image_01}`?

## Question

How do I define a latex function that takes as an argument the name of an image (`image_01.png`) and outputs:

```
\includegraphics[width=3em,valign=c]{image_01.png}
```

So that I can call this function multiple times with different arguments in math mode:

```
\[ \functionA{image_01.png} \functionA{image_02.png} \functionA{image_03.png} \]
```

Comment: `\newcommand\functionA[1]{\includegraphics[width=3em,valign=c]{#1}}`. Or better, `\newcommand\functionA[2][]{\includegraphics[width=3em,valign=c,#1]{#2}}` so that you can use options if you need, like `\functionA[width=4em]{image_01.png}`.

Comment: Off topic: observe that `\[ \]` is for displayed math mode, so it is strange to use it only to insert a graphic. Instead, use `figure` environment, for example.

Comment: Thanks @phelypeoleinik.  Your first comment answered my question completely!